# What is the difference between classification and prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction, definition

What is the difference between classification and prediction in machine learning?

Comment: See: https://www.kdnuggets.com/faq/classification-vs-prediction.html and http://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Functionality

- **Classification** is about determining a (categorial) class (or label) for an element in a dataset
- **Prediction** is about predicting a missing/unknown element(continuous value) of a dataset

#### Working Strategy

- In **classification**, data is grouped into categories based on a training dataset.
- In **prediction**, a classification/regression model is built to predict the outcome(continuous value)

#### Example

In a hospital, the grouping of patients based on their medical record or treatment outcome is considered *classification*, whereas, if you use a classification model to predict the treatment outcome for a new patient, it is considered a *prediction*.

Answer (score 18):

Classification is the **prediction** of a *categorial* variable within a predefined vocabulary based on training examples.

The prediction of *numerical* (continuous) variables is called *regression*.

In summary, classification is one kind of prediction, but there are others. Hence, prediction is a more general problem.

Comment: Even I had this doubt for quite some time. So in a broader sense, classification, regression all are different types of predictions right?

Answer (score 4):

**Classification** is the process of identifying the category or class label of the new observation to which it belongs.
**Predication** is the process of identifying the missing or unavailable numerical data for a new observation. 
That is the key difference between classification and prediction. The predication does not concern about the class label like in classification.

Answer (score 1):

Predictions can be using both regression as well as classification models. It means that once a model is trained on the training data; the next phase is to do predictions for the data whose real/ground-truth values are either unknown or kept aside to evaluate the performance of model. If the nature of the problem is of determining classes/labels/categories athen its classification and if the problem is about determining real numbers (numeric) values then its regression. In nutshell, predictions are supposed to done with both classification and regression for the test data set.

Answer (score 1):

1.**Prediction** is like saying something which may going to be happened in future.Prediction may be a kind of classification

2.**Prediction** is mostly based on our future assumptions

whereas

1.**Classification** is categorization of the things or data that we already have with us.This categorization can be based on any kind of technique or algorithms

2.**Classification** is mostly based on our current or past  assumptions